# What version of Perl introduced lexical my subroutines?

Tags: perl, language-features, lexical-closures

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/perl-sub-deprecate/issues/1) one of my modules is generating this error on older Perls,

> Experimental "my" subs not enabled at <file.pm> ...

What should I set my minimum perl version too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`perldoc perlexperiment`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlexperiment)

> Lexical subroutines
>
> - Introduced in Perl 5.18.0
> - Accepted in Perl 5.26.0